# Can you kill Iron Golems?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to kill an Iron Golem? I have tried to hit it with my diamond sword but that failed. If you can kill them please tell me how to. And what materials are needed to kill the Iron Golems. Also what loot will it give you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They have a lot of hitpoints, it'll take more than a few swings to hit them, but they do go down eventually.

A better method to kill them would be to suffocate them using Sand or Gravel. They cannot drown and take no damage from falling, meaning any trap will have to use Suffocation to kill them.

When killed, they drop Iron Ingots and Poppies.

Check out [this tutorial](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Iron_golem_farm) on how to build effective Iron Golem Farms. Further, you can read more about Iron Golems in general on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Golem)

Comment: Can you use tnt

Comment: Creepers can kill Iron Golems, so yes, TNT should kill them as well. And glad I can be of assistance :)

Comment: Is it one tnt block ot is it multiple

Comment: @Robotnik Since when can't iron golems drown? I am undereducated, I should have known this. :)

Comment: Please, keep the comments section for comments on the question and answer at hand; requests for clarification, additional notes, etc. If you'd like to have a more social conversation, I'd suggest checking out [chat].

Comment: @JamesOfDaPeach - According to the Wiki they can't drown. I haven't tried drowning them myself. The exact quote is *"They can take damage from weapons, lava, fire, poison, cacti, and suffocation. They do not take fall damage or drowning damage. Even though they won't get damaged, if a golem is underwater, it will not attack or move."*

Comment: @Robotnik The wiki can always be wrong, but acknowledged. I am pretty confident in that they still take fall damage though, I'll check on that tomorrow and edit the wiki to say it's wrong... :P

Comment: @JamesOfDaPeach, check out this video regarding fall damage: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1NkuYaJUzQ

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it has 100 health points though.  Try to get it aggroed by night time mobs so that they will attack it for you.

If you kill it, it will drop iron ignots and poppy.  Read more about them [Iron Golem Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Golem)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, it takes too long to kill because they have 100hp, I have an example.[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just use an enchanted diamond sword. It only takes a few hits with it, and dont get cocky, because I got killed by one. They drop iron ingots, so it's a waste of iron blocks and pumpkins. They drop roses, too.

Answer (score -1):

I just recommend that you don't kill iron golems with your popularity going down by 10. Those are bodyguards for villages and so don't kill those poor guys.

Oh they will kill you quicker than you attack them and that is not good.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Take the [Tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and have a look through the [Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help). While your answer is not incorrect, it doesn't answer the question asked.